# Adding and removing classes on mouse enter and leave on canvas shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to add a class to a element when mouse hovers over it and then remove it when mouse leaves. It works currently only with giving it direct style in js.

As shown below I tried various ways to do this, all had some problems. Only the direct style change worked. On mouse leave I do the same but remove the class. The mouse over and leave checks canvas element.

```
poly.on('mouseover', function () {
                this.opacity(1);
                layer.draw();
                $('.' + this.name()).css({ backgroundColor: "#ffcc00" });
                //$('.' + this.name()).classList.add("textboxhighlight"); 
                //$('.' + this.name()).className += " textboxhighlight";  
                //$('.' + this.name()).addClass("textboxhighlight"); 
                //$('.' + this.name()).setAttribute("class", "textboxhighlight"); 
            });
```

I'm not sure what the problem is as I tired various methods in adding class all of them with different problems. Using just `this.addClass` wont work as it needs to start with `$('.' + this.name())` or nothing works in the code not even forcing the style part. `$('.' + this.name())` refers to a class name in element with the same name as poly.

In css:

```
.textboxhighlight {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: using only css with .class:hover {} is not an option here ?
maybe the code isnt enough to show us what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have to use in your css class `background-color: #red !important`. See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/8525/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provided more code to work with. The example below will illustrate on how to add a class on hover and remove a class on leaving the element.

```js
$('#element').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
}, function(a) {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='element'>
  element
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is wrong with your code when you don't show the mouseenter/leave parts of your code. But here is an example with classes:
https://codepen.io/andeersg/pen/MOGqPQ

```
$('.el').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('el-hover');
});
$('.el').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('el-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass on hover event

```js
$(".hoverclass").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hoverclass_toggle");
});
```

```css
 .hoverclass {
     height: 72px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 .hoverclass_toggle {
     background-color: #000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoverclass">
    <div class="item">
        <div id="item1"> <i class="icon"></i>Test</div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Otherwise you can do that type :

```js
$(".hoverclass").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("result_hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
  }
);
```

```css
 .hoverclass {
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .result_hover {
    background-color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hoverclass">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="item1">
      <i class="icon"></i>Test
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```